# More Pythonic (or perhaps functional) way of creating this list?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm returning a list of lists, but the following seems far more convoluted than it should be:

```
new_list = []
for key, value in group.items(): 
    new_list.extend([['%s%s%s%s%s' % (
    ncode, vendor, extra, value['suffix'], tariff),
    value['latest_cost'], value['rrp'], value['rb']] for tariff in value['trf']])
return new_list
```

Comment: Well, perhaps you *could* cram this into one giant list comprehension, but it would be even less readable. This code is building something very complex from lots of sources, we cannot possibly use these dozen several things without typing them out. Perhaps there's something to improved at design level (it seems that at least three things are stored redundantly galore and the data structure seems very weird in general), but if you want this exact result, there's little anyone can do.

Comment: That's fair comment, and I agree, so +1. I've inherited the code, and am attempting to make improvements where I can, currently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not particularly convoluted. You have two "levels", the items in the group which you are expanding into one level. For doing that it's not very convoluted.

A more *functional* way would be to merge it all into one nested list expression, I think that could be possible. But it sure wouldn't be more readable, and personally I think that's unpythonic (ie, I don't like it).

Personally I would change that list expression to a for loop as well, for readability.

```
new_list = []
for key, value in group.items(): 
    for tariff in value['trf']:
        name = ''.join(ncode, vendor, extra, value['suffix'], tariff)
        new_list.append(name, value['latest_cost'], value['rrp'], value['rb']])
return new_list
```

Well, in fact, I would make a generator out of it, because I like them:

```
def tariffs(group):
    for key, value in group.items(): 
        for tariff in value['trf']:
            name = ''.join(ncode, vendor, extra, value['suffix'], tariff)
            yield [name, value['latest_cost'], value['rrp'], value['rb']]
```

You might also want to consider making objects out of this. As soon as you have lists of lists or dictionaries of dictionaries it's worth considering making classes instead.

Comment: I take both your and delnan's point re: the overall structure being…less than ideal, currently. That generator *is* a lot more readable.

Comment: Syntax error on the list, Also whats wrong with `''.join(str(i) for i in (ncode, vendor, extra, value['suffix'], tariff)) `

Comment: @S.Lott: Nah, I like the generator second, it's like one step at a time. :)

Comment: @Jakob: You are right, ''.join() is better in this case. I'll update.